# How to implement custom ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter in ASP.NET Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, csrf, asp.net-core-webapi, antiforgerytoken

I'd like to implement a filter that skips validation of an antiforgery token when an auth token authentication (`Bearer`) is used.

In the ASP.NET Core 2.2 the [`ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/Filters/ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter.cs) and  [`AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/Filters/AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter.cs) were public (even though living in the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal` namespace), so I was able to just inherit from the latter and override the `ShouldValidate` method easily.

In the ASP.NET Core 3.0 they became internal, so it's not possible to just inherit from them. I can just copy-paste the code, but it's not the ideal solution obviously.

I was following the [Prevent Cross-Site Request Forgery (XSRF/CSRF) attacks in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-3.1) article from MSDN, but it doesn't really mention anything relevant to my scenario.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Normally you can use `[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]` attribute if you can determine at compile-time that the csrf token should be ignored. If you want such an ability at run-time, you could create a custom **`FilterProvider`** that will **provide an `IAntiforgeryPolicy`** if there's a `Authroization: Bearer json-web-token` header.

For example, we can create a custom `AutoSkipAntiforgeryFilterProvider` as below:

```cs
public class AutoSkipAntiforgeryFilterProvider: IFilterProvider
{
    private const string BEARER_STRING = "Bearer";
    public int Order => 999;
    public void OnProvidersExecuted(FilterProviderContext context) { }
    public void OnProvidersExecuting(FilterProviderContext context)
    {
        if (context == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context)); }
        if (context.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.FilterDescriptors != null)
        {
            var headers = context.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers;
            if (headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
            {
                var header = headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault();
                if(header.StartsWith(BEARER_STRING,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    var FilterDescriptor = new FilterDescriptor(SkipAntiforgeryPolicy.Instance, FilterScope.Last);
                    var filterItem = new FilterItem( FilterDescriptor,SkipAntiforgeryPolicy.Instance);
                    context.Results.Add(filterItem);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // a dummy IAntiforgeryPolicy
    class SkipAntiforgeryPolicy : IAntiforgeryPolicy, IAsyncAuthorizationFilter
    {
        // a singleton 
        public static SkipAntiforgeryPolicy Instance = new SkipAntiforgeryPolicy();
        public Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context) => Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And register this filter provider in Startup :

```
services.TryAddEnumerable( ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IFilterProvider, AutoSkipAntiforgeryFilterProvider>());
```

Now it will bypass the `AntiForgery` even there's a `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`attribute.

---

**[Demo]**

Assume we have an action method annotated with `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name")] XModel xModel)
{
    ....
}
```

Normally, it will protect this method with CSRF token. But if you send a request like:

```
POST /XModels/Create HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer Xyz 
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

...
```

it won't validate the csrf token.

Comment: Great, works like a charm, thank you! 
One thing that wasn't completely obvious to me was where to register it - I added it initially inside the `services.AddMvc(config => { //here })` block, and it didn't work.
My final setup is as follows:
`services.TryAddEnumerable(ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<IFilterProvider, SkipAntiforgeryWhenAuthTokenUsedFilterProvider>());
services.AddMvc(config => { config.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute()); });`

Comment: @GrzegorzSmulko Glad to hear that it works for you. Just as a side note,  we prefer Endpoints routing over `UseMvc()`  :)

Comment: Thanks! One more thing, I tried to get rid of `AddMvc()` as you suggested - it totally makes sense, as I don't need any views/razor related functionality. The problem is, that it seems that there is no other way of adding `ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter` to the services than by running `AddViews` (or `AddMvc`, that calls it), because `ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter` is internal in the latest release of ASP.NET Core. Or maybe I'm doing something totally wrong and I should not be calling `config.Filters.Add(new AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute())` at all?

Comment: @GrzegorzSmulko 1. *I don't need any views/razor related functionality*: As far as I know, Antiforgery  is a View feature, if you don't want view, you don't need Antiforgery too :) 2. *ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter is internal*: Yes, that's true. But if you add `AddControllersWithViews()`, you don't need register it manually. it is registered by ASP.NET Core itself. We only need to register the *AutoSkipAntiforgeryFilterProvider* service, since it implements the `IAntiforgeryPolicy`, the `ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter` will skip Antiforgery token automatically.

Comment: My understanding was that CSRF is a problem in general for all the requests that modify the application state if an auth cookie is used. This also includes applications that use other UI mechanisms that ASP.NET Views or Razor pages. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-3.1#javascript-ajax-and-spas .

Comment: Yes. You're right. In a nutshell, CSRF happens because the browser sends a faked request (from other site) with credentials **automatically**. When sending a payload of `application/json`, we don't have to care about CSRF (for the present) since a request with `application/json` won't be sent to server by browser automatically. That's why ASP.NET Core treats the CSRF a View Feature(Here the View is a general term including MVC/Razor Page/a Plain Html Page/SPA/... ). Since ASP.NET Core treats this a very basic view feature, enable the Views will also enable this CSRF validation filter.

Comment: I'm picking up the discussion about CSRF and view-less Web APIs here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62347212/how-to-configure-anti-forgery-protection-in-a-view-less-web-api

Comment: `But if you add AddControllersWithViews(), you don't need register it manually` - if you do want to add manually, how do you do that?