# How to make a custom ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have looked everywhere but could not find code on how to create a custom AntiforgeryTokenAttribute using Asp.net Core. I've found examples based on older versions of Asp.net but not Core. I want to add some logic for when the token is validated to only validate based on some business rules. I've tried creating a new attribute inheriting AntiforgeryTokenAttribute but there doesn't seem to be any override that lets me control when to validate and when to ignore a forgery token.

Comment: There is no `AntiforgeryTokenAttribute` in asp.net core. Do you mean `ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute`? I think you need check the source code for [ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.cs) and [ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/bc1efeb10be465d042dd4856cbe6a93819f1565f/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/Filters/ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter.cs).

Comment: @Rena Yes I did mean ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute, the Validate got left off some how. I did look at the code for ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute but didn't know ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter existed. I'll take a look at that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this can help you, it creates a custom attribute like antiforgerytoken
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59550210/7071238

Comment: This helped in putting the pieces together to create a custom filter. Thanks!